# How to properly structure the dependencies of a netstandard1.0 NuGet package?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core

I updated a PCL with profile 259 to .NET Standard 1.0 and want to update the corresponding NuGet package accordingly. I changed the folder containing the actual DLL from `portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81` to `netstandard1.0`, **but I am not quite sure how to structure the dependencies of the package**.

If I use the .NET Core CLI to create a package (`dotnet pack`), the dependencies section in the nuspec file simply looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework="netstandard1.0">
    <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.0" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

However, when I install this package to a classic .NET 4.5 or PCL project that still uses packages.config, then this file gets "polluted" with all the dependencies from the `NETStandard.Library` metapackage, like so:

[image: "polluted packages.config file containing all the dependencies from NETStandard.Library 1.6.0]

1. Shouldn't this be avoided? One way to do that is to create empty dependency groups in the nuspec file [as suggested by Oren Novotny on the GitHub page of NuSpec.ReferenceGenerator](https://github.com/onovotny/ReferenceGenerator/#packages-containing-netstandard-and-existing-libraries). However, he himself discourages this in [one of his recent blog posts](https://oren.codes/2016/06/23/portable-is-dead-long-live-netstandard/).
2. Should I target the whole NETStandard.Library metapackage or just the packages that I actually need? Wasn't the idea of .NET Standard / .NET Core being easily runnable on all platforms that support the dependencies of your package?

Unfortunately, the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/nuget-packages) for NuGet packages with .NET Core / .NET Standard is not written yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had to address this problem for packages I maintain that target both .NET Core and .NET 4.5. The approach I use touches on both points of your question:

1. In project.json, split the dependencies up between `netstandard1.X` and `net45`. Initially, use the `NETStandard.Library` metapackage to make targeting the former easy.
2. Replace `NETStandard.Library` with references to the specific packages I actually need.

In the first step, my project.json looks something like this:

```
{
   "dependencies": {
      "MyOtherLibrary": "1.0.0"
   },
   "frameworks": {
      "net45": {
         "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Collections":"4.0.0.0"
         }
      },
      "netstandard1.3": {
         "dependencies": {
            "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Any dependencies that themselves are already compatible with either framework go in `dependencies`, while specific .NET Core or .NET 4.5 dependencies go in their respective sections as needed.

With `dotnet pack`, this produces exactly what I need: a single `.nupkg` that can be installed in either type of project and pulls in only what it needs for that framework.

In the second step, I swapped out `NETStandard.Library` with the few packages I actually needed for .NET Core:

```
{
   "dependencies": {
      "MyOtherLibrary": "1.0.0"
   },
   "frameworks": {
      "net45": {
         "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Collections":"4.0.0.0"
         }
      },
      "netstandard1.3": {
         "dependencies": {
            "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.11",
            "System.Net.Http": "4.1.0"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This second step isn't necessary, but it's nice to produce a package with minimal dependencies for both platforms. `NETStandard.Library` is useful in the development phase, when you're not quite sure what you'll need to use in the core API.